# Cannot find symbol error with BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, readline

Here is my error:

[image]

I'm unsure as to what I've done wrong here. Thank in advance

Comment: It would help if you could post your code and error message as text, not as an image.

Comment: use `readLine()` instead of `readln()` There doesn't exist a method named `readln` in `BufferedReader`

Comment: Please paste your code and error, instead of providing link of images

Comment: Class `BufferedReader` does not have a method named `readln`. It does have a method named `readLine`. Is that what you wanted to use instead? See the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

Comment: Reading error messages is really not that complicated (in cases like this). The compiler already tells you that it cannot find a certain symbol, shows you the exact location in the code and even specifies the symbol itself (method readln()) and it's location. All you have to do is read it and you'll get to the same conclusion a couple of people already commented on. H simply doesn't have a method called readln. It's very difficult to find an error message that is easier to understand than this one.

Comment: Thanks guys, don't know how I missed that. Clearly haven't been sleeping too well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't exist a method named `readln` in [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). Probably, you intended to use [BufferedReader#readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()), like

```
while((ln = H.readLine())!=null){
```

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I missed that.